# How to re-enable hover filter effect with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

### The issue

When i add a filter with javascript it over rides both the standard filter and the the hover filter. So i need a way to re enable the hover effect.

### What i want to be able to do

Am trying to make a gallery of black and white pictures, where when you hover over them they get colorized. The user should then be able to press the pictures, witch should blur them and show a description of them over the pictures. Then if the user presses another picture the first one should be reset.

Code for making a simple version of what am trying to do:

**Html code**

```html
<a href="#"  onclick="return false" onmousedown="image_blur();">
  <img id="test_image" src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/evening-in-the-forest-picture-id494297755?b=1&k=6&m=494297755&s=612x612&w=0&h=2FxNtXQgUVOfGD-ndkq3mdnnxq2LABWKM-7MkSX3uZY=" alt="">
</a>

<a href="#"  onclick="return false" onmousedown="remove_blur();">
  <p>
    Reset
  </p>
</a>
```

**CSS code**

```css
p {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#test_image {
  filter: grayscale(80%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%);
  -moz-filter:    grayscale(80%);
  -ms-filter:     grayscale(80%);
  -o-filter:      grayscale(80%);
}

#test_image:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -moz-filter:    grayscale(0%);
  -ms-filter:     grayscale(0%);
  -o-filter:      grayscale(0%);
}
```

**Javascript code**

```js
function image_blur() {
  var background = document.getElementById("test_image");
  background.style.WebkitFilter= "blur(2px)";
  background.style.filter= "blur(2px)";
}

function remove_blur() {
  var background = document.getElementById("test_image");
  background.style.WebkitFilter= "grayscale(80%)";
  background.style.filter= "grayscale(80%)";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding style with JS make them inline so they will always override any other style defined in the CSS (even the `hover` ones) so it's not a good idea to handle it in this way.

Instead consider adding/removing classes where you define your style. Then simply append the blur to the grayscale filter to apply both of them.

```js
function image_blur() {
  var background = document.getElementById("test_image");
  background.classList.add('blur');
}

function remove_blur() {
  var background = document.getElementById("test_image");
  background.classList.remove('blur');
}
```

```css
p {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#test_image {
  filter: grayscale(80%);
}

#test_image.blur {
  filter: grayscale(80%) blur(2px);
}

#test_image:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

#test_image.blur:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%) blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="image_blur();">
  <img id="test_image" src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/evening-in-the-forest-picture-id494297755?b=1&k=6&m=494297755&s=612x612&w=0&h=2FxNtXQgUVOfGD-ndkq3mdnnxq2LABWKM-7MkSX3uZY=" alt="">
</a>

<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="remove_blur();">
  <p>
    Reset
  </p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple example with some images

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JppOZy)

---

**Markup**

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://...">
    <img src="https://...">
    <img src="https://...">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img { filter: grayscale(80%); cursor: pointer; }
img:hover { filter: grayscale(0); }

img.selected { filter: grayscale(80%) blur(2px); }
img.selected:hover { filter: grayscale(0) blur(2px); }
```

**Javascript**

```
let gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery');
let currentSelection = gallery.querySelector('.selected');

gallery.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
   let tgt = ev.target;
   if (tgt.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {

      if (currentSelection) {
         currentSelection.classList.remove('selected');
      }

      currentSelection = tgt;
      currentSelection.classList.add('selected');
   }

});
```

The script detects a click over an image in the parent element (via [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) which is more performant than setting a single handler for each image), then apply a `selected` class to the image itself and remove that class from a previous selected image (if any). That class is styled in CSS so to show the `blur()` filter.

Note, I've cleaned the markup removing the links, since it seems they were not actually used to link a resource (I've noticed you `return false` on click),